# WPF DispatcherTimer does not fire

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm-light, dispatchertimer

I have a class with RefreshAsync method which can take a long time to execute. 
I am using Mvvm light framework. 
I need to call it after object created but not everytime when I get it's instance from servicelocator

```
var vm = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<FileSystemViewModel>();
```

So I use `DispatcherTimer` to create deferred update logic. But it does not fire and I don't know why.

Here is the code

```
private DispatcherTimer _timer;

public FileSystemViewModel()
{
    _timer = new DispatcherTimer(DispatcherPriority.Send) {Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(20)};
    _timer.Tick += DefferedUpdate;
    _timer.Start();
}

private async void DefferedUpdate(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    (sender as DispatcherTimer)?.Stop();
    await RefreshAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

Comment: And what if I create DispatcherTimer instance in DispatcherHelper.CheckBeginInvokeOnUI(() => ...) ? Will it work?

Answer (score 3):

Creating a `DispatcherTimer` must be done from a thread with an active `Dispatcher` or by passing an active dispatcher to the timer's constructor, e.g.

```
new DispatcherTimer(Application.Current.Dispatcher)
```

You should also consider if you really need a `DispatcherTimer`... A view model could most of the time do with a regular timer (e.g. `System.Timers.Timer`). Or in your case, even better - a simple `Task.Delay` in the async method:

```
private async Task DefferedUpdate()
{
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(20)).ConfigureAwait(false);
    await RefreshAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```